# Vertex position relative to normal

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, hlsl, cg, geometry-surface

*In a surface shader*, given the world's up axis (and the others too), a world space position and a normal in world space, how can we rotate the worldspace position into the space of the normal?

That is, given a up vector and a non-orthogonal target-up vector, how can we transform the position by rotating its up vector?

I need this so I can get the vertex position only affected by the object's rotation matrix, which I *don't* have access to.

Here's a graphical visualization of what I want to do:

- Up is the world up vector
- Target is the world space normal
- Pos is arbitrary

The diagram is bidimensional, but I need to solve this for a 3D space.

[image: vector diagram]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not passing the rotation matrix to the shader? That seems like the most obvious solution, so I'm assuming there's some information missing.

Comment: @rutter Unity doesn't expose the rotation matrix to the shader, according to 2 hours of Googling. If it were so easy!

Comment: I haven't hacked much on Unity shaders, but [this manual page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html) suggests that you should have several matrices available. It sounds like you'd want `UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV`?

Comment: @rutter Isn't the inverese transpose of MV for converting from camera space to world space? What I need is something like `_World2Object`, but only the rotation part.

Comment: I don't fully understand the math, but it's the same transformation that's [typically used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/what-is-the-logic-behind-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse) to adjust normals from model space to world space. That seems like the same (or similar?) transformation you're seeking here.

Comment: @rutter Hmm, I did experiment doing `mul(UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, IN.worldPos)`, but this zeroes the length of the position?

Comment: Nevermind, I screwed up. But now the value changes with camera movement!

Comment: You said you want to get vertex position but you can't get it in the surface shader. I think you meant the pixel's world position. Anyways, since I am not experienced with shaders, I usually try random stuff until I get what I want. I hope this code gives you some idea, even if it is not what you want exactly.

`float4 Pos=float4( IN.worldPos.x, IN.worldPos.y,IN.worldPos.z,1.0 ) - mul( _Object2World, float4( 1,1,1,1) )`

Comment: If you use the upper left 3x3 part of the `_World2Object` you get a matrix with only rotation and scaling. For which effect do you need the transformed position? The use case seems to be a bit unusual, maybe there is another approach to solve your problem.

Comment: @Gnietschow: I've created a shader that generates a grid according to some parameters. This shader is placed on a plane, which can be rotated and scaled. What I need to do is that the grid projects correctly considering the rotation of the object, but not its scale. The position is irrelevant, a solution that does or doesn't account for it will be acceptable. This is because the grid scaling should only be driven by the material parameters, not the object scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to rotate **pos** by the same rotation that would transform **up** to **new_up**.

Using the rotation matrix found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d), we can rotate **pos** using the following code. This will work either in the surface function or a supplementary vertex function, depending on your application:

```c
// Our 3 vectors
float3 pos;
float3 new_up;
float3 up = float3(0,1,0);

// Build the rotation matrix using notation from the link above
float3 v = cross(up, new_up);
float s = length(v);  // Sine of the angle
float c = dot(up, new_up); // Cosine of the angle
float3x3 VX = float3x3(
    0, -1 * v.z, v.y,
    v.z, 0, -1 * v.x,
    -1 * v.y, v.x, 0
); // This is the skew-symmetric cross-product matrix of v
float3x3 I = float3x3(
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1
); // The identity matrix
float3x3 R = I + VX + mul(VX, VX) * (1 - c)/pow(s,2) // The rotation matrix! YAY!

// Finally we rotate
float3 new_pos = mul(R, pos);
```

This is assuming that **new_up** is normalized.

If the "target up normal" is a constant, the calculation of **R** could (and should) only happen once per frame. I'd recommend doing it on the CPU side and passing it into the shader as a variable. Calculating it for every vertex/fragment is costly, consider what it is you actually need.

If your **pos** is a vector-4, just do the above with the first three elements, the fourth element can remain unchanged (it doesn't really mean anything in this context anyway).

I'm away from a machine where I can run shader code, so if I made any syntactical mistakes in the above, please forgive me.

Answer (score -3):

Not tested, but should be able to input a starting `point` and an `axis`. Then all you do is change `procession` which is a normalized (0-1) float along the circumference and your point will update accordingly.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 point;
    Vector3 origin = Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 axis = Vector3.forward;
    float distance;
    Vector3 direction;
    float procession = 0f;  // < normalized

    void Update() {
        Vector3 offset = point - origin;

        distance = offset.magnitude;
        direction = offset.normalized;

        float circumference = 2 * Mathf.PI * distance;

        angle = (procession % 1f) * circumference;

        direction *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle, axis);
        Ray ray = new Ray(origin, direction);

        point = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this was clear due to the tags and the first sentence, I need to do this in a shader. Specifically, a surface shader. In shaders, there's only matrices and vectors to deal with. No quaternions or rays.

Comment: @Zze what does HLSL mean?

Comment: @Minzkraut High Level Shader Language, its a language for programming visual effects on DirectX platforms.