# Normals move with model

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I wrote shader for diffuse lighting.
 
Normals rotate with rotation of 3D model, and its looks like when I rotate the model, light rotate to.

**Vertex Shader**

```
position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix *  gl_Vertex;
normal = vec4(gl_Normal, 1.0); <---
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
lightVector = normalize(vec4(lightPosition + cameraPosition, 1.0) - position);
resultNormal = normalize(normal.xyz); <---
```

How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: In which space are the normals in the image? Worldspace, Viewspace? How do you calculate them?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/what-is-the-logic-behind-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be transforming your normals with `gl_NormalMatrix`. Also, this line is suspicious:

```
normal = vec4(gl_Normal, 1.0);
```

Normals are directions, not positions, so their `.w` component should be 0.