# GPU Skeletal Animation and Normals. Is there fast way to get transpose(inverse(m))?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, normals, skeletal-animation

Writing hardware skinning for my game and need to animate normals too. From this [article](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/transforming-normals) I learned that usually to transform normals you need something like this:

```
transformed_normal = transpose(inverse(bone[i])) * normal;
```

I can't pass second set of precalculated transpose(inverse(bones)) to shader via uniforms because I don't have enough uniforms for that.
So I have to calculate this transpose(inverse(bone[i])) in vertex shader (again and again for every one of thousands vertices), isn't it?
Is there some faster way to do this? Some cheap and dirty approximation of this operation?

**Edit:** Found this cool solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46518010/9173149

Answer (score 6):

The typical way to handle this is to not put scaling in your bone matrices. If the bone transformations only have rotation and translation, doing the inverse/transpose is unnecessary.