# GLSL normal vector transformation

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In this glsl shader sample some vertex normal converted to the view space by transform: `vec4(vertNormal,1.0)).xyz`
Why we need to do this kind of the transformation?

```
#version 430
layout (location=0) in vec3 vertPos;
layout (location=1) in vec3 vertNormal;

void main(void)
{ 
...


// convert vertex position to view space
vec4 P = mv_matrix * vec4(vertPos,1.0); // looks good

// convert normal to view space
vec3 N = normalize((norm_matrix * vec4(vertNormal,1.0)).xyz); // why to vec4 and back to vec3?
...
}
```

Comment: Anway this is wrong. It has to be `N = normalize(mat3(norm_matrix) * vertNormal);` for an [Orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) and  `N = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(norm_matrix))) * vertNormal);` else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model view matrix looks like this:

```
( X-axis.x, X-axis.y, X-axis.z, 0 )
( Y-axis.x, Y-axis.y, Y-axis.z, 0 )
( Z-axis.x, Z-axis.y, Z-axis.z, 0 )
( trans.x,  trans.y,  trans.z,  1 )
```

The upper let 3*3 is contains the orientation and the scale. The 4th row contains the translation.
While for the transformation of a point the full matrix has to take into account, for the transformation of a direction vector only the orientation is of interest.

In general the normal matrix is a `mat3` and the `inverse`, `transposed` of the upper left 3*3 of the model view matrix. See

- [Why is the transposed inverse of the model view matrix used to transform the normal vectors?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor)
- [Why transforming normals with the transpose of the inverse of the modelview matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/why-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse-of-the-modelview-matr)

```
 mat3 norm_matrix;
```

```
 vec3 = normalize(norm_matrix * vertNormal);
```

The normal matrix can be calculated from the model view matrix:

```
mat4 mv_matrix;
```

```
mat3 norm_matrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(mv_matrix));
vec3 N = normalize(norm_matrix * vertNormal);
```

If the model view matrix is an [Orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) then the `inverse`, `transpose` can be skipped, because the inverse matrix is equal to the transposed matrix.
See [In which cases is the inverse matrix equal to the transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156735/in-which-cases-is-the-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-transpose)

```
vec3 N = normalize(mat3(mv_matrix)* vertNormal);
```

If you want to do the calculations in view space, then you have to transform the vertex coordinate from model space to view space:

```
vec4 P = mv_matrix * vec4(vertPos,1.0);
```

and you have to transform the direction of the normal vector form model space to view space:

```
vec3 N = normalize(norm_matrix * vertNormal);
```