# How to determine the orientation of a geometry surface in Scenekit

Tags: ios, glsl, shader, scenekit, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to write a shader to colorize a custom geometry in SceneKit. I want to set the colors so that horizontal surfaces that are facing up are white, horizontal surfaces that are facing downward are black, and all other surfaces in between are shades of gray based on their orientation. I used the material's surface entry point to call the following shader

```
vec4 normal = vec4(_surface.normal, 1.0);

// Assume value is [-1, 1], scale to [0, 1]
float color = normal.z * 0.5 + 0.5;

_surface.diffuse = vec4(color, color, color, 1.0);
```

It appears that the `normal.z` is relative to the camera (or view). I assume I need to transform the value, so that it's in another space. I tried multiple transforms (and combinations of transforms) such as `u_inverseViewTransform`, but the results all seem to be in view space. Does anyone know how to colorize a geometry based on the orientation of its surfaces?

Comment: `vec3 normal = mat3(u_inverseViewTransform) * _surface.normal;` should do the job.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that did it. Thanks. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `_surface.normal` is a vector in view space, you have to transform the vector to world space.

The transformation of a point form world space to view space is done by `u_viewTransform`, so the inverse operation (from view space to world space) can be done by `u_inverseViewTransform`.

`_surface.normal` is a direction vector, but not a point. A vector has to be transformed by the normal matrix, which is the transposed, inverse of the upper left 3*3 matrix of a 4*4 matrix:

```
transpose(inverse(mat3(u_viewTransform)))
```

See [Why is the transposed inverse of the model view matrix used to transform the normal vectors?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor), [Why transforming normals with the transpose of the inverse of the modelview matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/why-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse-of-the-modelview-matr)

But since `u_viewTransform` and `u_inverseViewTransform` are [Orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) the transposed, inverse can be skipped, because the inverse matrix and the transposed matrix are equal. See [In which cases is the inverse matrix equal to the transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156735/in-which-cases-is-the-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-transpose).

This follows you have to transform by `mat3(u_inverseViewTransform)`:

```
vec3 normal = mat3(u_inverseViewTransform) * _surface.normal;

float color = normal.z * 0.5 + 0.5;

_surface.diffuse = vec4(color, color, color, 1.0);
```