# Loading a Collada (dae) model from Assimp shows incorrect normals

Tags: c++, glm-math, collada, assimp

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Rabbid76, I needed to update the `Normal` vector in the vertex shader with the model matrix. Updated vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 projection; 
uniform mat4 view; 
uniform mat4 model;

uniform float scale;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 0.0));
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

**QUESTION**

I am trying to correctly load a collada (dae) file in Assimp, but the normals seem to come out wrong. I would like help with figuring this out. I have a feeling it is to do with how I am handling the transformation matrix. As an example, here's a screenshot of the OpenGL application loading an obj file:

[image]

In the above screenshot, the light is positioned directly above the models at  x=0 and z=0. The normals are displaying correctly. When I load a dae file, I get the following:

[image]

The light position seems to be coming from the -z side.

here is the code I currently have to load the models:

1. Load the model file, and call the `processNode()` method which includes an `aiMatrix4x4()`

```
void Model::loadModel(std::string filename)
{
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(filename, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace | aiProcess_GenBoundingBoxes);

    if (!scene || !scene->mRootNode) {
        std::cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP Could not load model: " << importer.GetErrorString() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        this->directory = filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of('/'));

        this->processNode(scene->mRootNode, scene, aiMatrix4x4());
    }
}
```

2. `processNode()` is a recursive method which primarily iterates over `node->mMeshes` i multiply the transformation.

```
void Model::processNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene, aiMatrix4x4 transformation)
{ 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++) {
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];

        // only apply transformation on meshs not entities such as lights or camera.
        transformation *= node->mTransformation;

        this->meshes.push_back(processMesh(mesh, scene, transformation));
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        processNode(node->mChildren[i], scene, transformation);
    }
}
```

3. `processMesh()` handles collecting all mesh data (vertices, indices etc)

```
Mesh Model::processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene, aiMatrix4x4 transformation)
{
    glm::vec3 extents;
    glm::vec3 origin;

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices = this->vertices(mesh, extents, origin, transformation);
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices = this->indices(mesh);
    std::vector<Texture> textures = this->textures(mesh, scene);

    return Mesh(
        vertices,
        indices,
        textures,
        extents,
        origin,
        mesh->mName
    );
}
```

4. Next the `vertices()` method is called to get all the vertices. It passes the transformation matrix. Here, i multiply the vertices with the matrix (`transformation * mesh->mVertices[i];`). I have a strong feeling that I am not doing something right here, and I am missing something.

```
std::vector<Vertex> Model::vertices(aiMesh* mesh, glm::vec3& extents, glm::vec3 &origin, aiMatrix4x4 transformation)
{
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++) {
        Vertex vertex;

        glm::vec3 vector3;

        aiVector3D v = transformation * mesh->mVertices[i];

        // Vertices
        vector3.x = v.x;
        vector3.y = v.y;
        vector3.z = v.z;

        vertex.position = vector3;

        // Normals
        if (mesh->mNormals) {
            vector3.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector3.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector3.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.normal = vector3;
        }


        // Texture coordinates
        if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0]) {
            glm::vec2 vector2;

            vector2.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
            vector2.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
            vertex.texCoord = vector2;
        }
        else {
            vertex.texCoord = glm::vec2(0, 0);
        }

        if (mesh->mTangents) {
            vector3.x = mesh->mTangents[i].x;
            vector3.y = mesh->mTangents[i].y;
            vector3.z = mesh->mTangents[i].z;
            vertex.tangent = vector3;
        }

        // Bitangent
        if (mesh->mBitangents) {
            vector3.x = mesh->mBitangents[i].x;
            vector3.y = mesh->mBitangents[i].y;
            vector3.z = mesh->mBitangents[i].z;
            vertex.bitangent = vector3;
        }


        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    glm::vec3 min = glm::vec3(mesh->mAABB.mMin.x, mesh->mAABB.mMin.y, mesh->mAABB.mMin.z);
    glm::vec3 max = glm::vec3(mesh->mAABB.mMax.x, mesh->mAABB.mMax.y, mesh->mAABB.mMax.z);

    extents = (max - min) * 0.5f;
    origin = glm::vec3((min.x + max.x) / 2.0f, (min.y + max.y) / 2.0f, (min.z + max.z) / 2.0f);

    printf("%f,%f,%f\n", origin.x, origin.y, origin.z);

    return vertices;
}
```

As an added note, if it is helpful, here is the fragment shader i am using on the model:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 Normal;  
in vec3 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

vec3 lightColor = vec3(1,1,1);
vec3 objectColor = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
uniform float shininess = 32.0f;
uniform vec3 material_specular = vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
uniform vec3 light_specular = vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

void main()
{
    // ambient
    float ambientStrength = 0.2;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), shininess);
    vec3 specular = light_specular * (spec * material_specular);  

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 projection; 
uniform mat4 view; 
uniform mat4 model;

uniform float scale;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = aNormal;  
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What is `FragPos` and `Normal`? Are they both in world space? Do you transform `FragPos` and `Normal` from model space to world space?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have added the vertex shader. `FragPos` is in world space. The uniform `model` is an identity matrix (`glm::mat4(1)`).

Comment: Are you sure that `model` is the identity matrix for all 3 objects. Doesn't have each of the 3 objects a model transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FragPos` is a position in world space, because it is the vertex position transformed by the model matrix. `lightPos` and `viewPos` seems to be positions in world space, too.
So have to transform the normal vector `aNormal`, from model space to world space, too.

You have to transform the normal vector by the the **inverse** **transposed** of the upper left 3*3, of the 4*4 model matrix:

```c
Normal = transpose(inverse(mat3(model))) * aNormal;
```

Possibly it is sufficient to transform by the upper left 3*3, of the 4*4 model matrix:
(See [In which cases is the inverse matrix equal to the transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156735/in-which-cases-is-the-inverse-matrix-equal-to-the-transpose))

```c
Normal = mat3(model) * aNormal;
```

---

<sub>See also:

[Why is the transposed inverse of the model view matrix used to transform the normal vectors?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor)

[Why transforming normals with the transpose of the inverse of the modelview matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/why-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse-of-the-modelview-matr)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I understand what I was doing wrong. I fixed it by calculating the world space of the normal vector: `Normal = vec3(model * vec4(aNormal, 0.0));`.

This fixed the lighting.