# Problem with diffuse lighting with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, lighting

My diffuse lighting doesn't seem to be working properly.

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 gl_FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;
in vec2 texelCoord;
in vec3 Normal;

struct DirectionalLight
{
    vec3 color;
    float ambientIntensity;
    vec3 direction;
    float diffuseIntensity;
};

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight;

void main()
{
    vec4 ambientColor = vec4(directionalLight.color, 1.0f) * directionalLight.ambientIntensity;
    
    float diffuseFactor = max(dot(normalize(Normal), normalize(directionalLight.direction)), 0.0f);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(directionalLight.color, 1.0f) * directionalLight.diffuseIntensity * diffuseFactor;
    
    gl_FragColor = texture(textureSampler, texelCoord) * (ambientColor + diffuseColor);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texelCoord;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 transformation;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * transformation * vec4( position, 1.0f );
    vertexColor = vec4(clamp(position, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f);
    
    texelCoord = texCoord;
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(transformation))) * normal;
}
```

How I create Meshes:

```
void CalcAverageNormals( unsigned int* indices , unsigned int indicesCount , float* vertices , unsigned int verticesCount , unsigned int vertexLength , unsigned int normalOffset )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < indicesCount; i += 3 )
    {
        unsigned int v1 = indices[i] * vertexLength;
        unsigned int v2 = indices[ i + 1 ] * vertexLength;
        unsigned int v3 = indices[ i + 2 ] * vertexLength;

        glm::vec3 line1( vertices[ v2 ] - vertices[ v1 ] , vertices[ v2 + 1 ] - vertices[ v1 + 1 ] , vertices[ v2 + 2 ] - vertices[ v1 + 2 ] );
        glm::vec3 line2( vertices[ v3 ] - vertices[ v1 ] , vertices[ v3 + 1 ] - vertices[ v1 + 1 ] , vertices[ v3 + 2 ] - vertices[ v1 + 2 ] );
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize( glm::cross( line1 , line2 ) );

        v1 += normalOffset;
        v2 += normalOffset;
        v3 += normalOffset;

        vertices[ v1 ] += normal.x; vertices[ v1 + 1 ] += normal.y; vertices[ v1 + 2 ] += normal.z;
        vertices[ v2 ] += normal.x; vertices[ v2 + 1 ] += normal.y; vertices[ v2 + 2 ] += normal.z;
        vertices[ v3 ] += normal.x; vertices[ v3 + 1 ] += normal.y; vertices[ v3 + 2 ] += normal.z;
    }

    for ( int j = 0; j < verticesCount / vertexLength; j++ )
    {
        unsigned int offset = j * vertexLength + normalOffset;
        glm::vec3 normalVertex( vertices[ offset ] , vertices[ offset + 1 ] , vertices[ offset + 2 ] );
        normalVertex = glm::normalize( normalVertex );

        vertices[ offset ] = normalVertex.x;
        vertices[ offset + 1 ] = normalVertex.y;
        vertices[ offset + 2 ] = normalVertex.z;
    }
}

void CreateTriangle() {

    float vertices[] {
       -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Left
        0.5f,-0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Right
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top
        0.0f,-0.5f, 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f  // Back Z
    };

    unsigned int indices[]{
        0, 1, 2, // Front
        3, 2, 1, // Right
        3, 2, 0, // Left
        3, 0, 1  // Bottom
    };

    CalcAverageNormals( indices , 12 , vertices , 32 , 8 , 5 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
    {
        Mesh* obj = new Mesh();

        obj->CreateMesh( vertices , 32 , indices , 12 );
        meshlist.push_back( obj );
    }

}
```

CreateMesh()

```
void Mesh::CreateMesh( float* vertices , unsigned int numVertices , unsigned int* indices , unsigned int numIndices )
    {
        uIndices = numIndices;
    
        glGenVertexArrays( 1 , &vao );
        glBindVertexArray( vao );
    
        /*Create Buffers*/
        glGenBuffers( 1 , &ibo );
        glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , ibo );
        glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , numIndices * sizeof(unsigned) , indices , GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    
        glGenBuffers( 1 , &vbo );
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , vbo );
        glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , numVertices * sizeof(float) , vertices , GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    
        glVertexAttribPointer( 0 , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof( vertices[ 0 ] ) * 8 , 0 );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
        glVertexAttribPointer( 1 , 2 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof( vertices[ 0 ] ) * 8 , ( void* )( sizeof( vertices[ 0 ] ) * 3 ) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        glVertexAttribPointer( 2 , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof( vertices[ 0 ] ) * 8 , ( void* )( sizeof( vertices[ 0 ] ) * 5 ) );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
    
        /*Unbind Objects*/
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , 0 );
    
        glBindVertexArray( 0 );
    
        glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , 0 );
    }
```

I only get some sort of lighting if I rotate the mesh:

[image: img]

Normal ( No lighting):

[image: img]

I been trying to figure this out for a days but I am not sure what I did wrong. If you could help me that would be great.

Comment: You are manipulating the vertices (`vertices[ v1 ] += normal.x;` ...),  while iterating the face and computing the face normal vectors. This affects the normal vectors of all following faces, which are defined by the manipulated vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was my order of indices having problem with triangle winding. I fixed this by drawing the indices in counter clockwise order because of how my diffuse factor is calculated.

```
unsigned int indices[]{
    0, 1, 2, // Front
    3, 1, 2, // Right
    3, 0, 2, // Left
    3, 1, 0  // Bottom
};
```

The transpose and inverse calculation is to correct non-uniform scale matrices.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(transformation))) * normal;
```

looks suspicious the normal itself should be transformed into the same coordinate system as the light direction vector is in. As normal is a vector the `w` should be zero so I would expect either

```
Normal = view * transformation * vec4( normal, 0.0f );
```

if the light direction is in camera coordinates or:

```
Normal = transformation * vec4( normal, 0.0f );
```

if the light direction is in global world coordinates (which is more likely the case)...

Also setting shader output variable like `gl_Position` should be the last line of your shader or you risk GL implementation optimize out the rest of code after it on some implementations.

btw. IIRC  `mat3(transpose(inverse(transformation)))` is the same as `mat3(transformation)` in case the `transformation` but as Rabbid76 pointed out it has its purpose...

One last thing I can think of is wrong normal direction (opposite or inconsistent) in such case I would try exchange:

```
max(dot(normalize(Normal), normalize(directionalLight.direction)), 0.0f);
```

with:

```
abs(dot(normalize(Normal), normalize(directionalLight.direction));
```

If it helps you have to check the normals or just negate the dot result...

For more info see:

- [OpenGL - vertex normals in OBJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) ... however there I use `w=1` as the matrix used has no offset so it does not matter
- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Comment: If `transformation` contains an asymmetrical scale, you need to use `mat3(transpose(inverse(transformation))`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 hmm good point I do always use symmetrical and unit  ones so didn't come to my mind ...  so it will do sort of aspect ratio inverse correction ? However in such case the code should work in firstplace ...  so there must be something else fishy in there

Comment: Yes of course. I didn't mean to blame it, it was just a note.

Comment: @Rabbid76 dont worry I took it for such right away was just currious I understand what it does correctly... maybe you could edit it in the answer ...

Comment: There are 2 good questions to explain "inverse/transpose": [Why is the transposed inverse of the model view matrix used to transform the normal vectors?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/why-is-the-transposed-inverse-of-the-model-view-matrix-used-to-transform-the-nor) and [Why transforming normals with the transpose of the inverse of the modelview matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654401/why-transforming-normals-with-the-transpose-of-the-inverse-of-the-modelview-matr)